# Pause video on Tab switch in browser but should continue Playing when minimized the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

I am trying to pause the video when the user switches the tab in the browser and simultaneously if the user minimizes the browser window it should not get paused.
I tried it implementing by using PageVisibility Api but using it the video gets paused in both cases.
I only need to pause if the tab is switched on, not in case the window is minimized.

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        if(document.visibilityState==="hidden")
        {
            videoElement.pause();
        }
        else if(document.visibilityState==="visible")
        {
            videoElement.play();
        }      
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    if (document.hidden){
        console.log("Browser tab is hidden")
    } else {
        console.log("Browser tab is visible")
   }
});
```